# UpdateFormValue is dispatched before the form value is changed

Tags: angular, ngxs

The UpdateFormValue action is dispatched before the form value is changed so this is not possible to do anything when the UpdateFormValue completes as the first action completes earlier than expected. Please for your assistance.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new ShowLoading());
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofActionSuccessful(UpdateFormValue),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(new HideLoading());
    });

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
            // Fetch by id.
            if (params?.id) {
                this.store.dispatch(new FetchById(params.id));
            }
        }
    );
}

@Action(FetchById)
fetchById(context: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>, action: FetchById) {
    // Get the data.
    this.articleService.fetchArticleById(action.id).subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
        if (response.isValid() && response.isSuccess()) {
            const article: Article = this.getModelData(response).pop();

            context.patchState({current: article});

            context.dispatch(
                new UpdateFormValue({
                        path: 'articles.form',
                        value: article
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your code sample doesn't demonstrate when the UpdateFormValue action is dispatched

Comment: Just added the action where the UpdateFormValue is dispatched. Event I comment this out the UpdateFormValue is dispatched by the form plugin.